# How to get user input to name a file

Tags: c++, fstream, iostream, journal

I've been trying out how to get user input to name a file that will then be created, I've been trying to make a journal application that can make notes and store them in files. Anyways here is the code

```
#include "main.h"
#include <string>

char  Start;

int main()
{
    int input;

    std::fstream fFile;

    std::cout << "*******" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Journal" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*******" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Enter any value to continue..." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> Start;
    system("CLS");
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "....." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "[1] Create New Note" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "[2] Browse Note Libary" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> input;

    if (input == 1)
    {
        std::string NoteName;
        std::cout << "Enter New Notes Name" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> NoteName;
        fFile.open("NoteName.txt"); // Here is what I can't figure out
        fFile << "test" << std::endl;
        fFile.close;

    }

    if (input == 2)
    {



    }



}
```

Main.h just includes the includes and make it so I can call the main function (:

Comment: Just use variable `NoteName` instead of text string `"NoteName.txt"` and it should work. Just don't forget to check that file opened successfully, because it may not for different reasons, including invalid name.

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
fFile.open(NoteName);
```

or if you want to add ".txt" to the name the user entered

```
fFile.open(NoteName + ".txt");
```

The way you are trying is called string interpolation. It works in some languages but not C++.